# Multiple performance metrics with stratified cross validation

Tags: python, machine-learning, classification, cross-validation

I have a small, imbalanced dataset which I want to test with different algorithms. For evaluation purposes I need multiple performance metrics (accuracy, precision, recall, fscore, support).

Thats the way I plan to do it but I'm not really satisfied, since there might be a simpler solution:

```
skf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=3, random_state=42, shuffle=True)
accuracy = []
for train_index, test_index in skf.split(X,Y):
    X_train, X_test = X[train_index], X[test_index]
    y_train, y_test = Y[train_index], Y[test_index]
    gradientBoost.fit(X_train, y_train)
    y_pred = gradientBoost.predict(X_test)

    accuracy.append(round(accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred), 2))
    precision, recall, fscore, support = np.round(score(y_test, y_pred), 2)

    print('precision: ' + str(precision))
    print('recall: ' + str(recall))
    print('fscore: ' + str(fscore))
    print('support: ' + str(support))

    print(classification_report(y_test, y_pred))

meanAcc= np.mean(np.asarray(accuracy))
print('meanAcc: ', meanAcc)
```

In theory I could to the averaging for all metrics like I did for accuracy. Is there a simpler and/or more efficient approach?

EDIT:

I tried plotting accuracy and recall_weighted as scorers. Unfortunately only accuracy shows in the plot. In the legend accuracy + recall are mentioned.

```
#Initialize classifier
clf_gini = DecisionTreeClassifier(criterion = "gini", random_state = 42,
                               max_depth=10, min_samples_leaf=8)

scoring = {'Accuracy' : make_scorer(accuracy_score), 'Recall' : 'recall_weighted'}

gs = GridSearchCV(DecisionTreeClassifier(criterion= 'entropy', random_state=42, min_samples_leaf = 10), param_grid={'max_depth' : range(2, 30, 2)},
                  scoring=scoring, cv=3, refit='Accuracy')

gs.fit(X_Distances, Y)
results = gs.cv_results_

plt.figure(figsize=(13, 13))
plt.title("GridSearchCV evaluating using multiple scorers simultaneously",
          fontsize=16)

plt.xlabel("max_depth")
plt.ylabel("Score")
plt.grid()

ax = plt.axes()
ax.set_xlim(0, 32)
ax.set_ylim(0, 1)

# Get the regular numpy array from the MaskedArray
X_axis = np.array(results['param_max_depth'].data, dtype=float)

for scorer, color in zip(sorted(scoring), ['g', 'k']):
    for sample, style in (('train', '--'), ('test', '-')):
        sample_score_mean = results['mean_%s_%s' % (sample, scorer)]
        sample_score_std = results['std_%s_%s' % (sample, scorer)]
        ax.fill_between(X_axis, sample_score_mean - sample_score_std,
                        sample_score_mean + sample_score_std,
                        alpha=0.1 if sample == 'test' else 0, color=color)
        ax.plot(X_axis, sample_score_mean, style, color=color,
                alpha=1 if sample == 'test' else 0.7,
                label="%s (%s)" % (scorer, sample))

        best_index = np.nonzero(results['rank_test_%s' % scorer] == 1)[0][0]
        best_score = results['mean_test_%s' % scorer][best_index]

        # Plot a dotted vertical line at the best score for that scorer marked by x
        ax.plot([X_axis[best_index], ] * 2, [0, best_score],
                linestyle='-.', color=color, marker='x', markeredgewidth=3, ms=8)


    # Annotate the best score for that scorer
    ax.annotate("%0.2f" % best_score,
                (X_axis[best_index], best_score + 0.005))

plt.legend(loc="best")
plt.grid('off')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Why not append to a list or a dictionary itself? I am not sure what else you can do.

Comment: What do you mean by append to a list? For the accuracy I'm currently appending to a list, I could do that for all metrics, yes.

Comment: Yes, append them to a list like you are doing for accuracy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use [GridSearchCV for multi-metric evaluation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_multi_metric_evaluation.html):

```
# Author: Raghav RV <rvraghav93@gmail.com>
# License: BSD
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

from sklearn.datasets import make_hastie_10_2
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.metrics import make_scorer
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
```

#### Running GridSearchCV using multiple evaluation metrics¶

```
X, y = make_hastie_10_2(n_samples=8000, random_state=42)

# The scorers can be either be one of the predefined metric strings or a scorer
# callable, like the one returned by make_scorer
scoring = {'AUC': 'roc_auc', 'Accuracy': make_scorer(accuracy_score)}

# Setting refit='AUC', refits an estimator on the whole dataset with the
# parameter setting that has the best cross-validated AUC score.
# That estimator is made available at ``gs.best_estimator_`` along with
# parameters like ``gs.best_score_``, ``gs.best_parameters_`` and
# ``gs.best_index_``
gs = GridSearchCV(DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state=42),
                  param_grid={'min_samples_split': range(2, 403, 10)},
                  scoring=scoring, cv=5, refit='AUC')
gs.fit(X, y)
results = gs.cv_results_
```

#### Plotting the result

```
plt.figure(figsize=(13, 13))
plt.title("GridSearchCV evaluating using multiple scorers simultaneously",
          fontsize=16)

plt.xlabel("min_samples_split")
plt.ylabel("Score")
plt.grid()

ax = plt.axes()
ax.set_xlim(0, 402)
ax.set_ylim(0.73, 1)

# Get the regular numpy array from the MaskedArray
X_axis = np.array(results['param_min_samples_split'].data, dtype=float)

for scorer, color in zip(sorted(scoring), ['g', 'k']):
    for sample, style in (('train', '--'), ('test', '-')):
        sample_score_mean = results['mean_%s_%s' % (sample, scorer)]
        sample_score_std = results['std_%s_%s' % (sample, scorer)]
        ax.fill_between(X_axis, sample_score_mean - sample_score_std,
                        sample_score_mean + sample_score_std,
                        alpha=0.1 if sample == 'test' else 0, color=color)
        ax.plot(X_axis, sample_score_mean, style, color=color,
                alpha=1 if sample == 'test' else 0.7,
                label="%s (%s)" % (scorer, sample))

        best_index = np.nonzero(results['rank_test_%s' % scorer] == 1)[0][0]
        best_score = results['mean_test_%s' % scorer][best_index]

        # Plot a dotted vertical line at the best score for that scorer marked by x
        ax.plot([X_axis[best_index], ] * 2, [0, best_score],
                linestyle='-.', color=color, marker='x', markeredgewidth=3, ms=8)


    # Annotate the best score for that scorer
    ax.annotate("%0.2f" % best_score,
                (X_axis[best_index], best_score + 0.005))

plt.legend(loc="best")
plt.grid('off')
plt.show()
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Looks great. I have a multiclass problem, so I chose recall_weighted and accuracy as scorers. Unfortunately only accuracy is being plotted, any ideas? (I updated my initial post with my code)

Answer (score 1):

`sklearn` documentation proposes to use one of the following metrics for evaluating classifications:

- accuracy          metrics.accuracy_score
- average_precision     metrics.average_precision_score
- f1                    metrics.f1_score                    for binary targets
- f1_micro          metrics.f1_score                    micro-averaged
- f1_macro          metrics.f1_score                    macro-averaged
- f1_weighted       metrics.f1_score                    weighted average
- f1_samples            metrics.f1_score                    by multilabel sample
- neg_log_loss      metrics.log_loss                    requires predict_proba support
- precision           metrics.precision_score           suffixes apply as with f1
- recall                metrics.recall_score                suffixes apply as with f1
- roc_auc           metrics.roc_auc_score

lets try `accuracy` and `f1_weighted`:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.metrics import recall_score, make_scorer, accuracy_score
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier


X, y = make_classification(n_classes=10, n_informative=8, random_state=1)

scoring = {
  'Accuracy' : 'accuracy',
  'F1 (macro)' : 'f1_weighted',
}

scoring = {
  'Accuracy' : 'accuracy',
  'Recall' : 'f1_weighted',
}

gs = GridSearchCV(RandomForestClassifier(max_depth=5, random_state=42, min_samples_leaf = 10),
                  param_grid={'n_estimators' : range(2, 101, 2)}, return_train_score=True,
                  scoring=scoring, cv=3, refit='Accuracy')

gs.fit(X, y)
results = gs.cv_results_

##################
plt.figure(figsize=(12, 8))
plt.title("GridSearchCV evaluating using multiple scorers simultaneously",
          fontsize=16)

plt.xlabel("n_estimators")
plt.ylabel("Score")
#plt.grid()

ax = plt.gca()
ax.set_xlim(0, 101)
ax.set_ylim(0, 1)

# Get the regular numpy array from the MaskedArray
X_axis = np.array(results['param_n_estimators'].data, dtype=float)

for scorer, color in zip(sorted(scoring), ['g', 'k']):
    for sample, style in (('train', '--'), ('test', '-')):
        print('plotting: {} ({})'.format(scorer, sample))
        sample_score_mean = results['mean_%s_%s' % (sample, scorer)]
        sample_score_std = results['std_%s_%s' % (sample, scorer)]
        ax.fill_between(X_axis, sample_score_mean - sample_score_std,
                        sample_score_mean + sample_score_std,
                        alpha=0.1 if sample == 'test' else 0, color=color)
        ax.plot(X_axis, sample_score_mean, style, color=color,
                alpha=1 if sample == 'test' else 0.7,
                label="%s (%s)" % (scorer, sample))

        best_index = np.nonzero(results['rank_test_%s' % scorer] == 1)[0][0]
        best_score = results['mean_test_%s' % scorer][best_index]

        # Plot a dotted vertical line at the best score for that scorer marked by x
        ax.plot([X_axis[best_index], ] * 2, [0, best_score],
                linestyle='-.', color=color, marker='x', markeredgewidth=3, ms=8)


    # Annotate the best score for that scorer
    ax.annotate("%0.2f" % best_score,
                (X_axis[best_index], best_score + 0.005))

plt.legend(loc="best")

plt.grid(False)
plt.show()
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I found out a few minutes ago that I only thought the additional metric isn't plotted because for example recall_weighted is the same curve as accuracy. When I switch to macro its visible.

Comment: @user3667018, yeah, i've come to the same conclusion yesterday. I should have mentioned it in the answer...

Comment: Alright thanks a lot! Just another question: Is it reasonable to pass my whole dataset to `GridSearchCV(cv=3)`? I was just thinking about overfitting etc. but `GridSearchCV()` should handle the cross validation?

Comment: @user3667018, no, your model should not be able to see the test data set during the training, otherwise you'll experience "data leakage"...

Comment: How do I handle this when I want to do a stratified cross validation in the end? I don't have one single training/test set. After parameter tuning I'm training a new model using the found best parameters and perform cross validation.

Comment: @user3667018, there is no need to train your model again - `gs` will contain a __trained__ model, you can simply use `gs.predict()`, `gs.score()`, `gs.best_estimator_`, etc. I would suggest you to open a new question with a small reproducible sample data set and ask there a new question...